# ¿Rutas locales o rutas Http absolutas en un sitemap?

Tags: sitemap

He buscado por Internet y no consigo información de lo que estoy preguntando. Quisiera saber si un sitemap.xml admite rutas locales (Ejemplo: C:/xampp/htdocs/mipagina) O es necesario usar una ruta absoluta como la de cualquier sitemap (Ejemplo: http:://mipagina/acerca de/).

Apenas estoy trabajando con sitemap y quisiera saber eso.

> Claramente **C:/xampp/htdocs/mipagina** depende de que tipo de hosting lo alojes, eso varia

Comment: ¿Si tu web ya esta montada en un hosting, porqué quieres invocar rutas de localhost?

Comment: Hola. Mi web no está montada aun en un Hosting en Internet. Los ejemplos que puse "C:/xampp/htdocs/mipagina" es un ejemplo nada más. Quisiera saber si puedo usar ese tipo de rutas para el sitemap

Answer (score 0):

El sitemap no admite rutas locales ya que es un fichero para facilitar la tarea a los motores de búsqueda y que puedan llegar a aquellas páginas, incluso complejas que salen de una consulta a la base de datos.
Pero ellos no podrán acceder a una dirección local del disco duro.